# Web Ui popover Input focus Jquery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, web, focus, popover

I'm using a web ui popover (http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/).
I have a input field in the pop up.
However, I have tried different methods(setting a delay,.focus()) to set focus on the field and it is not working.

Please suggest what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onShow callback

```
$(function () {
     $('#pop').webuiPopover({
        onShow: function() {$('#myinput').focus();}
    });
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rqo92dmk/